# How to get data from html-table via php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have html-table and three buttons:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<table id="table"></table>

<input type="button" id="add" value="Add">
<input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete">
<input type="submit" id="save" value="Save">
</form>
```

You can see there are no rows in it by default.

In javascript I add rows and cells by clicking the button "Add". Also I can delete them by clicking the button "Delete".

When I finish adding rows and cells I click the button "Save". And by clicking "Save" I want to save the information in txt-file, for example. I know how.
As I am new in php, I am not an IT-guy, I do not want to work with MySQL, ajax, etc.

How is it possible to just take the information for html-table by php.
In test.php I wrote:

```
<?php
print_r ($_POST);
?>
```

to check whether I get the information or not. So I do not.

If you ask yourself why someone do not want to work with mysql and want to save the information in txt-file I can answer: it is probably easier for me as there is not so much information I will work with and I will not have to learn how to work with MySQL.

Comment: Try giving your inputs a name like `<input type="button" name="myName" value="Submit"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass along the data to PHP the HTML your using must have items in the form with [names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-name). Here is how that could look for you.

index.html

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <table id="table">
        <input type="text" name="rows[1][item1]" value="123test">
        <input type="text" name="rows[2][item1]" value="321test">
    </table>

    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add">
    <input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete">
    <input type="submit" id="save" value="Save">
</form>
```

test.php

```
<?php


var_dump($_POST);

/* output of $_POST above
array (size=1)
  'rows' =>
    array (size=2)
      1 =>
        array (size=1)
          'item1' => string '123test' (length=7)
      2 =>
        array (size=1)
          'item1' => string '321test' (length=7)
*/
```